# Django Admin Ask a User a List of Questions

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I am trying to create a custom Django Admin Site for new staff members that lets a staff member edit their User first_name/last_name + get presented a list of multiple choice questions with radio select for the answer choices. The questions need to be a predefined queryset (e.g. last 5 multiple choice questions by date_created), whether a M2M entries exists already or not.

[image: admin page diagram]

**models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid4,
        unique=True,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
    )


class Questions(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid4,
        unique=True,
    )
    question_text = models.CharField(
        max_length=160,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
    )
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(
         auto_now_add=True
    )
    users = models.ManyToManyField(
        Users,
        through=Questions2Users,
        through_fields=('questions', 'users')
    )


class AnswerChoices(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid4,
        unique=True,
    )
    choices_text = models.CharField(
        max_length=160,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
    )
    questions = models.ForeignKey(
        Questions,
        related_name='questions',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )


class Questions2Users(models.Model):
    questions = models.ForeignKey(
        Questions,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    users = models.ForeignKey(
         Users,
         null=True,
         blank=True,
         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    answerchoices = models.ForeignKey(
        AnswerChoices,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import (
    User,
    Questions,
    Answers,
    Questions2Users,
)

class Questions2UsersInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Questions2Users


class UserAdminSite(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    inlines = [
        Questions2UsersInline
    ]


admin.site.register(User, UserAdminSite)
```

I have identified it as a user model admin page with an inline for the M2M model. How would I display the questions queryset all at once with question_text and choice_text?

Comment: Can you share the actual models? `Question.answerchoices_id` suggests that there is a `ForeignKey` from `Question` to `AnswerChoices`, shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: sorry had originally posted from my mobile phone. Updated with a diagram + minimal example for models.py and admin.py